# Wireless not working after update

Tags: 12.04, wireless

After installing a bunch of updates to Ubuntu 12.04, my wireless connection stopped working. However, I found that I could access other wireless networks; I just couldn't access the one I had been using before the update. Is there any way to completely remove a wireless network and add it back in again so that it will be like a "new" wireless network and I'll be able to use it? (I tried deleting and adding it back in "Edit Connections" but this didn't work.) Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Update:

I removed the network connection that was not working using the command `sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/name-of-connection` and then confirmed that it was removed by generating a list of all the network connections. However, that didn't work.

For `cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a`, I got

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
Linux Aspire4830T 3.5.0-37-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 10 
17:48:11 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`, I got

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 
Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:054f]
```

### Kernel driver in use: atl1c

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9287 
Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e034]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

For `lsusb`, I got

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:d250 Suyin Corp.
```

For `iwconfig`, I got

```
 eth0      no wireless extensions.

 lo        no wireless extensions.

 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ubcsecure"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: A0:CF:5B:A3:DF:92   
      Bit Rate=117 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:9  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0
```

For `rfkill list all`, I got
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no

For `lsmod`, I got

```
 Module                  Size  Used by
  ath3k                  12969  0 
  btusb                  22432  0 
  pci_stub               12623  1 
  vboxpci                23237  0 
  vboxnetadp             25671  0 
  vboxnetflt             23479  0 
  snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32476  1 
  snd_hda_codec_conexant    62363  1 
  vboxdrv               282562  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
  coretemp               13642  0 
  kvm_intel             137888  0 
  kvm                   422160  1 kvm_intel
  joydev                 17694  0 
  acer_wmi               32845  0 
  sparse_keymap          13891  1 acer_wmi
  xt_hl                  12522  6 
  ip6t_rt                12559  3 
  nf_conntrack_ipv6      14107  7 
  nf_defrag_ipv6         13413  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
  ipt_REJECT             12577  1 
  xt_LOG                 17454  9 
  snd_hda_intel          34063  3 
  snd_hda_codec         135141  3                         
  snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
  snd_hwdep              17765  1 snd_hda_codec
  xt_limit               12712  12 
  xt_tcpudp              12604  18 
  snd_pcm                97523  3       
  snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
  uvcvideo               78117  0 
  videobuf2_core         33025  1 uvcvideo
  videodev              125126  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
  videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
  videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
  xt_addrtype            12714  4 
  xt_state               12579  14 
  microcode              23030  0 
  snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
  ip6table_filter        12816  1 
  snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
  ip6_tables             27686  2 ip6t_rt,ip6table_filter
  snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
  nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12666  0 
  nf_conntrack_broadcast    12590  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
  nf_nat_ftp             12705  0 
  nf_nat                 25646  1 nf_nat_ftp
  nf_conntrack_ipv4      14531  9 nf_nat
  snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
  nf_defrag_ipv4         12730  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
  arc4                   12530  2 
  nf_conntrack_ftp       13453  1 nf_nat_ftp
  nf_conntrack           83300  8       nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ftp
  mei                    41410  0 
  iptable_filter         12811  1 
  snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
  snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
  ip_tables              27474  1 iptable_filter
  x_tables               29892  12       
  xt_hl,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,xt_LOG,xt_limit, xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_state,ip6table_filter, ip6_tables,iptable_filter,ip_tables
  ath9k                 133095  0 
  psmouse               102506  0 
  mac80211              555272  1 ath9k
  ath9k_common           14054  1 ath9k
  ath9k_hw              399752  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
   ath                   24124  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
  serio_raw              13216  0 
  snd                    83674  16             
  snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec, 
  snd_hwdep, snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
  lpc_ich                17145  0 
  cfg80211              208382  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
  soundcore              15092  1 snd
  snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
  rtsx_pci_ms            13181  0 
  memstick               16606  1 rtsx_pci_ms
  bnep                   18240  2 
  parport_pc             32867  0 
  rfcomm                 47562  0 
  bluetooth             211860  12 ath3k,btusb,bnep,rfcomm
  ppdev                  17114  0 
  ext2                   73799  1 
  mac_hid                13254  0 
  lp                     17800  0 
  parport                46563  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
  dm_crypt               23126  1 
  rtsx_pci_sdmmc         17801  0 
  ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
  aesni_intel            51134  26 
  cryptd                 20531  10 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
  aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
  atl1c                  42092  0 
  ahci                   25869  2 
  libahci                27338  1 ahci
  i915                  535221  3 
  drm_kms_helper         49259  1 i915
  drm                   290595  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
  rtsx_pci               33680  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
  i2c_algo_bit           13565  1 i915
  video                  19653  2 acer_wmi,i915
  wmi                    19257  1 acer_wmi
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you are using? Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Ubuntu-Gnome remix?

Comment: user180894 you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged.  Once done you will be able to re-edit your question with further info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all connection files under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connection/

Use this command:

```
rm -iv /etc/NetworkManager/system-connection/*
```

Comment: Please open a terminal ctrl+alt+t copy and paste the following commands into it one line at a time, then edit your question to contain the results of these commands.  

`cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a`
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod`

Comment: I guess you commented a wrong post